# Use of a hamburger menu for minimalist design on desktop website?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, white-space

[Here is a link to my website](http://nicotesthostingpackage-com.stackstaging.com/portfolio/). My aim was to have a "minimalist" interface, with large font and lots of blank space. The idea was coming from the fact that I personally feel more like reading a webpage when the font is not too small! Consequently, I chose a hamburger menu so as to tuck the navigation away and make the page feel "lighter". As the website is pretty straight forward, I planned to rely on pretty obvious in context links (especially from the index page).

Yet, I wonder if this is not "too" minimalist? Am I the only one who likes "white space"? More specifically, **what do you guys think of using the hamburger menu in this context on desktop version?** I could be argued that such navigation style is unclear and counter intuitive, although it feels quite natural to me...

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. Please review the guidelines for asking questions in the "help" at the top of the page. Then, please edit your question to more closely conform to those rules. Here we concentrate on problems to be solved rather than with different opinions and advice, per se. The question also borders on User Interface practice as much as graphic design.

Comment: I personally have no problem whatsoever with large white areas nor with hamburger icon. The only thing that bothered me was its right-top position: I did not find it was a very natural position as I'm a left-to-right reader. Now I see you live in Japan and maybe it does make sens if you want to reach a Japanese audience.

Comment: You should include image(s) of your website so that this question can be more useful to others once you change your website around

Answer (score 1):

This is really a very broad question, and highly subjective.  So, only a personal observation here - sure it's fine as long as all your users know what a hamburger icon is for.

If they are all young, or familiar with phones/tablets/mobile apps etc, then fine.  If not, change the hamburger icon to the word "Menu" instead.  It doesn't have to be big, and it can still be minimalist.

Another thing - mousing over the hamburger icon doesn't even show up as a tooltip (title attribute).  This is something you need to address for desktop sites if you choose to stick with the hamburger icon.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are overthinking here. There are cases where hidden navigation may cause negative user experience. Ask yourself why do you need to hide the menu in the first place. You may simply want to achieve a minimalist look, or you don't want your menu items to distract the user from focus on something important that is on the very page? Or may be you have way too much items to keep in the menu?

Basically, this would boil down to your objectives - your goals. Speaking from the design side, there isn't really a good or bad here. Whether your website is personal or otherwise, it is ideal to define an "audience" for your website and think from their perspective. Try to identify your prospective visitors' (employers offering internships in this case, I suppose) expectations and layout your design accordingly.